# Unable to access the package in rosws

Tags: calibration, stereo-camera, image-pipeline, rosws, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Im running on Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS fuerte.
I want to calibrate 2 individual cameras as a stereocamera.
I created an overlay using rosws in my home folder and then added several packages like uvc_camera, usb_cam, camera_umd and the stack mage_pipleine using the command *rosws set  --git*
After that i resourced the new setup.bash within my workspace.

When i tried to access my package camera_calibration inside the image_pipeline stack using roscd camera_calibration command, it went to the one in my /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/image_pipeline/camera_calibration instead of the one in my workspace associated with rosws.
This problem is only for this package, while i am able to access the other packages in my rosws using roscd.

I also checked the .rosintall file in my local workspace, it listed down all these entries.

Also i tried to install the dependencies of the camera_calibration packages using *rosdep install camera_calibration* and I am getting the error

**ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
camera_calibration: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [sensor_msgs]**

Could anyone kindly help me in resolving this.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52678/unable-to-access-the-package-in-rosws/) by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) on 2013-01-18**:
Thanks for your reply.
I did that too but in vain.

Please note that, it is working for all the other packages in the same workspace and does not work only for the camera_calibration.

My ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is set to

/home/hari/fuerte/image_pipeline:/home/hari/fuerte/camera_umd:/home/hari/fuerte/uvc_

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2013-01-31**:
Not sure why you name your own package with a same name as in the original stacks.. Could you pls try change your package name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

overlaying in fuerte works by searching for packages in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. You can investigate it by typing:

```
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

The first thing to check when your overlaying package is not found where it should it the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. The second thing to check is the exact spelling of the name of the package. Often, '-' and '_' are mixed up.

Finally try running

```
rospack profile
```

rospack caches locations of packages, and this rebuilds the cache.

The rosdep problem is unrelated and may better be asked in a separate question, or a ticket on the camera_calibration package.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1